# Describing a consistent learner

Tags: machine-learning

Let $X=R^3$.
Let $C=H=\{h(a,b,c)=\{(x,y,z) |x|\leq a,|y|\leq b, |z|\leq c\}, a,b,c\in R_+\}$ the set of all origin centered boxes.
Describe a polynomial sample complexity algorithm that learns $C$ using $H$.

Can you please explain what does it mean to describe an algorithm that learns $C$ using $H$?
What is the difference between $C$ and $H$?

Comment: That is certainly weird. Are you sure that in the problem description it states "$C=H=\dots$"?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, unless there's a mistake in my home assignment

Comment: Usually you learn a *single* function, by finding a close approximation to if from the hypothesis space $H$. Maybe here they meant that the approximated function is already in $H$? In any case, writing "$C=H=\dots$" does not really make a lot of sense. You might want to ask your teacher what he meant there, for further clarifications

Comment: Can you describe where you encountered this task?  We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: If you don't understand what the homework is asking you, I suggest asking your instructor.  We can't know what they have in mind.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141325/755, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/96578/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).